# How to retrieve one row from SQL Server datatable

Tags: sql-server-2008

[image]

I have one table with ‘N’ number of rows, I am trying to fetch one by one rows and want to perform some operation.

Can anyone help me with this stored procedure?

For more details: I am trying to retrieve mail id from 'UserMaster' table one by one, and I want to use this mail id to send mail to particular user, I am able to send mail to user,

Just struck retrieving them one by one

```
declare @count as int
declare @inti as int

select COUNT(UserId) from tblUserMaster where AccessLevelId = '1'

SET @inti = 1

while @inti <= @count
BEGIN
    select @mail = Email_ID 
    from User_Master 
    where AccessLevelId = '1' 
    rownum(@inti)     -- here I need to retrieve one bye one row

    @inti ++;

    EXEC sp_send_dbmail @profile_name = 'PinalProfile',
                        @recipients = @mail,
                        @subject = 'Test message',
                        @body = 'This is the body of the test message.
Congrates Database Mail Received By you Successfully.'
END
```

Comment: You never set the value of `@count`.  Did you meant `select @count = COUNT(UserId) from tblUserMaster where AccessLevelId = '1'`?

Comment: @VARUN, So what is the problem? if your problem is you don't get into the loop, the answer is in above comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple ways to do this, I think simplest way is to insert your resultset into a temp object with an identity column, then loop through temp object.  Here's some pseudo code:

```
DECLARE @t1 table (id int identity, email varchar(50)), 
    @count int,
    @i int = 1,
    @email varchar(50);

INSERT INTO @t1 (email)
    select Email_ID 
    from User_Master 
    where AccessLevelId = '1';

select @count = count(*) from @t1;

while @i <= @count
BEGIN
    select @email = email from @t1 where id = @i

    EXEC sp_send_dbmail @profile_name = 'PinalProfile',
        @recipients = @mail,
        @subject = 'Test message',
        @body = 'Test body';

    set @i = @i + 1;
END
```

Comment: Perfect answer Greg .Thank you very much